# Fieldset и Checkbox

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Из базы данных загружается в fieldset данные. Но почему то галочка ставится только в первом fieldset ?

```
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query1))
  {
  ?>
    <?php

    $id = $row['id']; ?>



      <fieldset>
          <input type="checkbox" name="check1" style="display:none">
        <br/>
<?php //echo $row['id']; ?>
      </fieldset>
        <?php
        }
            ?>
```

Как добиться чтобы чекбокс был в каждом fieldset ?

```
if(items.value==="1")
        {
            document.getElementsByName("check1").style.display="block";
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementsByName("check1").style.display="none";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему у Вас все чекбоксы с одним и тем же именем.

Попробуйте что-то типа этого:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query1))
  {
  ?>
    <?php

    $id = $row['id']; ?>



      <fieldset>
          <input type="checkbox" name="check<?php echo $id ?>" style="display:none">
        <br/>
<?php //echo $row['id']; ?>
      </fieldset>
        <?php
        }
            ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query1)):
    $id = $row['id']; 
?>
      <fieldset>
          <input type="checkbox" name="check[<?php echo $id ?>]" style="display:none">
          <br/>
          <?php //echo $row['id']; ?>
      </fieldset>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Не идет что-то(((